# Efficiency/comparison of sprintf vs paste0

Tags: r

I know `paste()` and `paste0()` are extremely popular in R, but I find myself often using `sprintf()` when I want to build a long string with some variables.

For example

```
x <- "a"
y <- 10
paste0("The value of x is ", x, " and y is ", y, ".")
sprintf("The value of x is %s and y is %d.", x, y)
```

I find the `sprintf()` version much easier to write and the code less clunky.  I couldn't find any discussion of the benefits of one over the other. Is there any reason for me not to use `sprintf()` when the basic functionality of `paste` is all I need? (if I need to use the `collapse` or `sep` arguments then obviously `sprintf()` will not do).

The only thing I can think of is that maybe `sprintf()` is slower because it checks that the types  match.

Answer (score 14):

One reason I could think of to use `paste0` or `paste` instead of `sprintf` is that you don't need to think about the types of arguments being passed.

In terms of efficiency, `sprintf` appears to have an edge, at least on the example you gave and my machine:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(paste0("The value of x is ", x, " and y is ", y, "."),
               sprintf("The value of x is %s and y is %d.", x, y))
# Unit: microseconds
#                                                   expr   min     lq    mean median     uq    max neval
#  paste0("The value of x is ", x, " and y is ", y, ".") 2.924 3.0185 3.45632 3.0950 3.1575 36.421   100
#     sprintf("The value of x is %s and y is %d.", x, y) 1.328 1.4130 1.54794 1.4535 1.5430  7.513   100
```

Comment: Wait, is that right?  Was that just for the one string?

Comment: I don't think you HAVE to think about types with sprintf, a lot of times you can get away with just using `%s` even if it's a numeric.  As I said, when the `collapse` or `sep` arguments should be used then I wouldn't use `sprintf`, but in the simple case of just building a string, I wonder why most people don't use sprintf?

Comment: @RichardScriven Yeah, I just added `stri_c` to my benchmark and it was actually the slowest of the 3 options. Not sure how generalizable results are (running on recent macbook air).

Comment: @RichardScriven are you asking if the benchmarking results are right? I'm also seeing on my ThinkPad machine that `sprintf` in this case is faster, by 3x

Comment: I just tried `do.call(paste0, ...)` and it was about 10ms, and I still get 10ms for stringi.  This just got interesting

Comment: @daattali since string combining is not usually a performance bottleneck, I think it definitely comes down to preference. Personally I don't like cluttering my code with %s symbols, so I would prefer `paste0`. It sounds like you're exactly the opposite, so I would definitely go with `sprintf`. At least on SO, I see `paste`/`paste0` a lot more than `sprintf`.

Comment: @josilber yes the performance diff is likely negligible, that's why I was wondering if there are any significant differences or if it's purely a matter of taste (as you just said).  If it truly is just a matter of preference, I'll accept that

Comment: Be careful.  People argue over fractions of a millisecond around here :-)

Comment: @RichardScriven, I *think* a better comparison would be `stri_flatten` but I hesitate to even bother trying to benchmark unless a better test set than a single sentence with two replacements is developed.

Comment: There is also gettextf(), a wrapper for sprintf, which offers a few other capabilities.   From its help:
gettextf is a convenience function which provides C-style string formatting with possible translation of the format string.